# custom external font in Core Ui bootstrap laravel

Tags: css, laravel, frontend, core-ui

I've been using CoreUI Bootstrap for my Admin panel and everything is working smoothly. For CSS and Js I used laravel mix and in _custom.sass file I defined font family as following code:

```
@font-face {
font-family: "vazir";
src: url('../../fonts/Vazir.ttf');
}
```

and I assigned it to body:

```
body {
font-family: "vazir", sans-serif !important;
}
```

On Localhost font is loaded and configured successfully but when I upload my project on real server font is default CoreUI font.

Comment: Is `../../fonts/Vazir.ttf`, case-sensitive, available on the server as well?

Comment: yes, same folder. Public/fonts

Comment: Does it show with a status 200 in the network panel (F12 -> Network)?

Comment: no, thanks for mentioning. It's showing 404 error. What should I do?

Comment: It's hard to tell, if the font is there physically. One possibility is that you have the wrong case somewhere in the path. Paths on Linux are case sensitive, on Windows they are not.
You could also try https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Vazirmatn instead

Comment: Thanks a lot. My problem is solved. It was problem with case sensitive

Comment: I make all my paths and filenames lowercase,  no matter what OS I'm using. Saves a lot of headache.